# how to convert data (format yyyy/mm/dd) from a csv to a vector in R (Rstudio)

Tags: r, csv, date, vector

I have a spreadsheet with only one column with several rows with dates in the format (yyyy/mm/dd) and I would like to convert it into a vector of the type without having to type it manually:

```
vector <- c ("yyyy/mm/dd", "yyyy/mm/dd", "yyyy/mm/dd", "yyyy/mm/dd", ...... "yyyy/mm/dd" , "yyyy/mm/dd", "yyyy/mm/dd", "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

file csv: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SrSnf5VP4YWuxPQNsQsiURLTRW4_Xf1u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: something like `df <- read.csv("path/to/file")` to read the file. And `as.Date(df$datas, format="%Y/%m/%d)`

Comment: `df1 <- read.csv("qmd7.csv", colClasses = "Date")`. See `help('as.Date')` argument `tryFormats` for the formats tried automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for the delay, the R is difficult.

I got it.

The responses from @emilliman5 and @Rui Barradas worked, mainly the command that was for my case:

as.Date(df$dates, format = "%Y/%m/%d")